# Extract time (given in AM/PM) from a character string in r

Tags: r, split

I want to extract time (along with AM/PM)present in character string into a list which can be rendered into selectizeInput. I went through other solution available on net but solutions were either too complex to comprehend or not reproducible. I appreciate if anyone could suggest the easy way out.

```
strg <- 'At 03:00 AM, 06:00 AM and 11:00 AM, only on Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, and Friday'
```

Expecting result as a list of time : `("03:00 AM","06:00 AM","11:00 AM")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `regmatches` with the pattern `\b\d{2}:\d{2} (?:AM|PM)\b`:

```
strg <- 'At 03:00 AM, 06:00 AM and 11:00 AM, only on Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, and Friday'
m <- gregexpr("\\b\\d{2}:\\d{2} (?:AM|PM)\\b", strg)
regmatches(strg, m)[[1]]

[1] "03:00 AM" "06:00 AM" "11:00 AM"
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(strg, "[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} [AP]M")[[1]]
#[1] "03:00 AM" "06:00 AM" "11:00 AM"
```